# Application NewMailEx before any other rules

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, mapi

I have an addon for outlook 2013 and later.

The main purpose of the addon is to move emails to folders and to change the subject line based on certain rules, (not outlook rules, but my own addon 'rules').

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  // ...
  // new email arrives.
  this.Application.NewMailEx += Application_NewMailEx;
}
```

Then move it to a folder and change the subject when the mail arrives

```
private async void Application_NewMailEx(string entryIdItem)
{
  Outlook.MailItem newMail = GetEmailWithId(entryIdItem); // get that email

  // ... move email and change the subject
}
```

But in some cases, a Desktop alert is fired as well as a sound been played, (based on the outlook rules themselves of course).

In the desktop alert I can see that the subject has not yet been changed so the outlook rules are applied before my addon had chance to move the message and change the subject.

So, how can I 'catch' an email before any rules, desktop alerts or anything are fired.

In other words, how can I position my addon first when it comes to handling emails when they arrive, before any rules are applied so the outlook rule can then handle the new subject and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - all of these events are asynchronous and their order is undetermined.

Comment: Are you sure? You can order the rules, and stop all rules once a certain rule has been completed. So that would tell me that they are synchronous, (in outlook 2013 at least).

Comment: Positive. The rules engine might be executing all the rules sequentially, but its gets the notification asynchronously.